# How to identify a unique Facebook user from a URL click

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a Proof of Concept requirement that from a static URL posted in an advertisement on Facebook, we identify the unique individual that clicked our link and has landed on our page (external to Facebook).

This static advertisement will have no coding associated with it (that is part of our challenge - and will just redirect the user to our site).

Is there anything within the stream of data that is sent in a normal redirect or available to us in anyway that would allow for the following:

1. Identify the user that clicked
2. Allow for a callback to Facebook to
       get any unique user information

Not sure it matters -- but we are looking at a .NET C# site as the landing page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t identify the Facebook user in any way without authorization. So when he visits the link, you need to implement authorization and you can check if it´s the same user with `FB.getLoginStatus`, for example. That function of the JavaScript SDK refreshes the Access Token so you don´t need to redirect to another page when it´s not valid anymore.

Here´s a tutorial, just in case: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

But remember: Nothing without authorization.